# Use Apple TV and iPad 2 in a car

Tags: ipad, appletv

How can I use an Apple TV with the iPad 2 where there is no internet WiFi? e.g. in a car?

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done. If you want to watch media on the iPad in a car, copy the media (music, movie, TV show, photo) to the iPad via iTunes before you leave.

Answer (score 1):

@Negrino is right, you cannot do this. What's stopping you from copying your movies etc onto the iPad and just using that? That's one of the main advantages of having such a beautiful portable device!

Answer (score 0):

Using an AC converter, you could run a Wi-Fi router in your car and set up a network with a lightweight media host.

Answer (score 0):

Neither device is capable of starting a wireless network, adhoc or otherwise.

However, you likely have a laptop with you.  You should be able to start an ad-hoc wireless network, attach both devices, then stream between the two.  You can also use a wireless router to set up a real network and attach to that.

Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish (watching digital movies on the go, watching streaming movies on the go, playing iOS games on the car TV, etc) there is likely a better solution to the problem than an apple tv, router, and ipad.  However it can be done if that is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done if you Jailbreak.

- Install [Mywi](http://intelliborn.com/mywi.html) on it and create a network.
- Use a power inverter in your car to power your Appletv 2
- Configure the AppleTv onto the new network you created

You now have full airplay in your car audio and video.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Thanks for your answer! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you